# splitting JSON objects into rows

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

```
"events": {
    "a": {
        "eventName": "a",
        "eventIdentifier": "abc"
    },
    "b": {
        "eventName": "b",
        "eventIdentifier": "xyz"
    }
}
```

I want to split events "a" and "b" into 2 different records using spark sql only and above json should not in array.

Output:

```
+---------+-------------------+
|eventname|eventidentifier    |
+---------+-------------------+
|a        |abc                |
|b        |xyz                |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the events "a" and "b" into two separate records using Spark SQL, you can use the explode function to transform the JSON structure. Here's a way to achieve this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object JsonSplitExample {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("JsonSplitExample")
  .master("local[*]")  // Change this for a cluster deployment
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val jsonString = """
  {
    "events": {
      "a": {
        "eventName": "a",
        "eventIdentifier": "abc"
      },
      "b": {
        "eventName": "b",
        "eventIdentifier": "xyz"
      }
    }
  }
"""

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS())

// Select the events field and explode it
val explodedDF = df.selectExpr("explode(events) as event")

// Select the fields from the exploded event structure
val resultDF = explodedDF.select(
  col("event.eventName").alias("eventName"),
  col("event.eventIdentifier").alias("eventIdentifier")
)

resultDF.show()
spark.stop()
```

}
}

Comment: `explode` function will take only `array` or `map` type.. but given input is of `struct` type.. hence this solution might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array` to create rows & `inline` functions to flatten or explode array of rows.

Logic - `inline(array(events.*))`

```
scala> spark.table("input").show(false)
+--------------------+
|events              |
+--------------------+
|{{abc, a}, {xyz, b}}|
+--------------------+
```

```
scala> spark.table("input").toJSON.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"events":{"a":{"eventIdentifier":"abc","eventName":"a"},"b":{"eventIdentifier":"xyz","eventName":"b"}}}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> spark.sql("""select inline(array(events.a,events.b)) from input""").show(false)
+---------------+---------+
|eventIdentifier|eventName|
+---------------+---------+
|abc            |a        |
|xyz            |b        |
+---------------+---------+
```

OR

```
scala> spark.sql("""select inline(array(events.*)) from input""").show(false)
+---------------+---------+
|eventIdentifier|eventName|
+---------------+---------+
|abc            |a        |
|xyz            |b        |
+---------------+---------+
```